# Dynamic Load of a DLL after ILMerge

Tags: c#, ilmerge

In a project, we dynamically load a .dll based on an objects settings.  Prior to ILMerge, this worked fine.  We now used ILMerge and created one .dll, but the load fails.  How do you dynamically load a .dll after it was ILMerged?  We are using VS2008 and C#.

DLLS:     Common.dll, CommonMedical.dll

NEW DLL:  DMCommon.dll

Current Code that Fails to load the .dll:
      asm = Assembly.LoadFrom("CommonMedical.dll");

What am I doing wrong?  I even tried .Load, and I do not see any issues with the name space because it works without ILMerging.  Thanks in advance,

Craig

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394325 ?

Comment: What are the full details of the error you get?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to Instantiate the class through .NET Reflection; merged with ILMerge](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394325/unable-to-instantiate-the-class-through-net-reflection-merged-with-ilmerge)

Comment: @chibacity - I get the following error:  Could not load file or assembly 'CommonMedical' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious answer, change your code to: asm = Assembly.LoadFrom("DMCommon.dll");

You've created a new merged assembly file and you're using the [LoadFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.loadfrom.aspx) which loads using a filename.

Comment: must be some confusion on my side... you say to use .LoadFrom as your answer, but then say that my error is using LoadFrom which loads using a file name.  Please clarify - thanks!

Comment: Preet Sangha added the second sentence to my original post. The LoadFrom API takes the name of the assembly on the drive, not the namespace, which is why you are required to use the new name of merged assembly.

Comment: wow, that was confusing on the post.  I did try what you suggested and I still get an error on not finding the assembly.